# jasmine unit testing failing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

Here is the function I am testing:

Utilities.js

```
    exports.calculateAgeTimeStamp = function(timestamp) {

        //get year

        var userYear = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
        min = userYear.getFullYear();

        //get current year
        var curYear = new Date();
        max = curYear.getFullYear();

        //work out age from current year
        return Math.abs(max - min);
    };
```

It takes a timestamp and calculates age.

Here is my spec:

```
    //test to see if timestamp converts to age.
it("timestamp should be converted to age > 20503539200", function() {
    //matcher
    expect(utilities.calculateAgeTimeStamp("20503539200")).toBeNumber();
});
```

Here is the error:

```
 [INFO] :   .   - timestamp should be converted to age > 20503539200 (FAILED)
    [INFO] :   .   - - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(utilities.calculateAgeTimeStamp("20503539200")).toBeNumber()') in file:///Users/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/F0A42483-4497-4670-AFEE-839D81C2E075/specs/lib/utilities_spec.js (line 12)
    [INFO] :   .  ============================================================
    [ERROR] :  .  THERE WERE FAILURES!
    [ERROR] :  .  ============================================================
    [ERROR] :  .  Recap of failing specs:
    [ERROR] :  .  ------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] :  .  utilities timestamp should be converted to age > 20503539200. - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expect(utilities.calculateAgeTimeStamp("20503539200")).toBeNumber()')
```

I know this function works, because it is working fine in my app. Any idea why I am getting this error, cheers.

Comment: How is utilities defined?

Comment: One of the following is true: A) `utilities` is not what you think it is. B) The matcher `toBeNumber` is mis-spelled.  C) The matcher is not being loaded.  Which of these three is the issue cannot be gleaned from what we have here.

Comment: https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers toBeNumber seems to be a function here(unless I am mistaken). And utilities is the file which stores the function  calculateAgeTimeStamp

Comment: just edited my OP, cheers.

Comment: Have you included Utilities.js in your config so that the file is loaded?